# If in a coordinated turn, the horizontal lift vector is equal to the Centrifugal force. Then how is the aircraft still turning?

Tags: aerodynamics, lift, flight-dynamics

[image: The Cetn]

[Image source](https://thebackseatpilot.com/pages/aerodynamics#:%7E:text=AERODYNAMICS%20OF%20A%20TURN&text=The%20VCL%20is%20opposed%20by,maintains%20a%20level%2C%20coordinated%20turn)

How does the Aircraft continue to turn when the both the Horizontal component of lift and the centrifugal force are equal?

Comment: https://thebackseatpilot.com/pages/aerodynamics#:~:text=AERODYNAMICS%20OF%20A%20TURN&text=The%20VCL%20is%20opposed%20by,maintains%20a%20level%2C%20coordinated%20turn.

Comment: Re the link above-- wow, the diagram labelled "Left bank, no back pressure" makes even worse errors.  Implies that the amount of back pressure you apply affects the vertical component of lift but not the horizontal component.  Fails to recognize that if true, this would create a skid (net aerodynamic force pointed to inside of turn, not "straight up", in a/c ref frame.)  Completely bogus.  In the hang gliding world an argument is sometimes made that inadequately pitching the nose up while turning creates a *slip* rather than a skid.  That's bogus too.  Slip/skid is about yaw not pitch.

Comment: Try it-- enter a turn and change the back pressure. You'll see little effect on the ball.

Comment: Just noticed that this question is a duplicate of https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/38040/how-can-an-aircraft-turn-if-the-horizontal-force-component-is-zero?rq=1 .  Some well-thought-out answers were posted there.

Comment: Related -- https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/79338/34686

Answer (score 6):

The forces in the first pictures would be as shown if you are observing situation from reference frame connected to the turning airplane. Then, *in this reference frame*, the airplane is not moving and therefore neither turning. Other forces, gravity and interaction with air molecules remains in place, so in order to make the description consistent, you need to add centrifugal force.

If you observe the situation from ground, there is no centrifugal force (because this fictitious/inertial force appears as a consequence of applying laws of motion in rotating reference system) and horizontal component of lift makes observed trajectory circular.

*Edit2: The later two images are not complete. Forces has to be always in balance if viewed from airplane's reference frame. They are missing part of aerodynamic force generated by side-wise motion through air, which is definition of slip and skid (you can call it drag or airframe-lift). See [@quietflyer's answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/101432/19344) for more details on this.*

Comment: Re "(if it should be a view from airplane's reference frame, CF and horizontal lift has to match always)" -- well, not if "horizontal lift" is only meant to include the horizontal component of the *wing's* lift and not the horizontal component of the aerodynamic sideforce from the airflow striking the side of the fuselage.  See my answer for more--

Comment: @quietflyer: True, I have realized this later, but had not found time to add it to my answer.

Comment: All *fictitious*, (non-inertial, psuedo forces), simply represent the acceleration of the frame of reference you are doing your analysis in. Doing your analyis in any accelerating, non-inertial frame invalidates Newton's kaws, ***UNLESS*** you add in an extra, fictitious force to represent the acceleration of the frame itself.

Answer (score 6):

> How does the Aircraft continue to turn when  both the Horizontal component of lift and the centrifugal force are equal?

**Those pictures are not 100% correct.**

To enter and keep a turn, a force toward the centre of the curve has to be created. In an airplane this is achieved by tilting the lift laterally, like in the following picture ([source](https://www.cfinotebook.net/graphics/maneuvers-and-procedures/airborne/Forces-In-A-Turn.jpg)) where the airplane is turning left (as seen from the front):

[image: Airplane in a turn]

The vertical component of the lift balances the weight out while the horizontal component keeps the airplane in a turn. This horizontal component is called centri**petal** force. The higher the centripetal force is, the steeper the turn is.

End of the story.

So what about the centri**fugal** force? Let's make an everyday comparison with what happen in car that accelerates. Due to the traction force the car gets accelerated **forward**. But what you experience as a driver/passenger is actually a **backward** force (aka inertia) pushing you against the seat. This is exactly the same as for our airplane: the centripetal force makes it bend leftward but what you experience is actually an opposite, rightward, centrifugal force. Those two forces have the same magnitude but opposite direction. Anyway is only the centripetal force that keeps the airplane in a turn. The centrifugal force is the inertia "felt" by the pilot/passenger and acting on all the non-lifting surfaces of the airplane.

Answer (score 5):

The centrifugal force is produced by the act of turning.  If you weren't turning, it would be zero.  If it were zero, you would have an imbalance of forces which would cause an acceleration that would cause you to turn.

Properly, the centrifugal force is not really a force, it is an acceleration.

$a=V^2/r$

Recall that we can write $F=m\,a$ where forces balance out accelerations.  So, the horizontal component of lift needs to balance out (or it causes) the acceleration in the turn.

As @Martin said, the second two images are bogus and the source that generated them doesn't understand what is going on.

Comment: I do think "force is balancing out acceleration" formulation is misleading. Force is _causing_ acceleration. In any reference frame. The problem with centrifugal force is that it is result of choosing accelerating _frame of reference_. So you could say, in some sense (this particular) force is "balancing out" acceleration of _frame of reference_ (even if it is bit unusual wording), but frame of reference is no real object. For any physical object, force is _causing_ acceleration, not "balancing" it.

Comment: @Martin Fair point -- I thought about wording things differently, but then I started to think about the acceleration due to gravity -- which we have in (what we consider) an inertial frame -- but that we often  freely replace with a force (weight).  I meant balance out to really imply algebraic equivalence.  And although the force undoubtedly causes the turn, when analyzing the problem, you may well observe the turn in order to then infer the force.

Comment: Acceleration causes Gravity, not the other way round,  or perhaps a better way of stating it is that they are the same thing. Think about it, how do we measure, or detect acceleration? With a G-meter. When we let Gravity accelerate us, (in free-fall), a g-meter will indicate zero.

Comment: I shouldn't have brought gravity into it.  It is a fundamental force of nature that is a body force (acts on all the mass simultaneously) rather than a point, pressure, or shear force that we're more used to thinking about.  Gravity is a force field.  If we are free to fall, then we accelerate at a fixed rate (due to gravity).  However, the acceleration does not cause it (the way an accelerating frame causes a force).  For if we can't fall, we still feel the force of gravity.  So a mystical force field causes the body force of gravity F=mg.

Answer (score 3):

Centrifugal force is a *fictitious* force, i.e., it is not real, it is added by engineers only to make the F=ma equation work in what is called a *non-inertial* or *accelerated* frame of reference. They can also be referred to as *Inertial* or *Psuedo* Forces. It is the same concept as trying to do F=ma for motion in a room on a rotating space station that has artificial gravity due to the rotation. In ***that frame of reference***, the cup of coffee on the table is not accelerating, it is motionless. To make the F-ma equation work, (to make the force F and the acceleration be zero we need to include a fictitious Centrifugal force to oppose and balance the centripetal force. Other forces which fall into this category include Coriolis force and Gravity.

That is exactly what is going on for the diagrams you are looking at for an aircraft in a steady state turn.

What is not addressed, (and rarely explained in basic flight training), is that Newton's rules of motion (F=ma for example), are only valid in an ***inertial*** or ***non-accelerated*** frame of reference. Unless you are in free-fall (experiencing zero acceleration), you are in a non-inertial or accelerated frame of reference, and some fictitious force must be added to your analysis to compensate for the acceleration of the frame of reference in which you are doing your analysis.

In addition, it must be remembered that *everything* is relative. Not just velocity. Most of us will agree that all velocities must be measured relative to some reference velocity. How fast is the earth moving? well, there is no correct answer unless you also specify "*with respect to what*"?  What is not generally understood is that the same concept also applies to acceleration.  Sitting in your chair in your living room, we are in fact in an accelerating frame of refence (as we *feel* acceleration), upwards. That is why Einstein's famous "thought experiment" is so illuminating. In it he explains that there is no way that someone can tell the difference between that situation, and being in a room in a spaceship in deep space that is accelerating with a rocket engine thrust at 32 feet per second squared. These two situations are not just similar, they are *equivalent*, (identical).  In both cases you are in a *non-inertial*, *accelerating* frame of reference, and a *fictitious force* must be added to any analysis to compensate for the intrinsic acceleration of the frame of reference to make any F=ma analysis equation balance properly.

Heree is a graphic from Misner, Wheeler & Thorne's ***[Gravitation](https://ia800101.us.archive.org/24/items/GravitationMisnerThorneWheeler/Gravitation%20Misner%20Thorne%20Wheeler.pdf)*** that illustrates this:
[image]

Comment: Note: centrifugal force is for most purposes as real as for example gravity. The fact that it appears because of choice of frame of reference does not make its effects less real. (You are actually telling just this in the last paragraph mentioning indistinguishably of gravity force and accelerating-frame forces.)

Comment: Actually, Gravity, as understood in the physics world, is also a "*fictitious*" force, as it is, according to General Relativity, (now pretty much accepted, verified and considered to be the current "correct" view of what gravity is),  is not a force at all, but just our perception of the straight-line path in space-time taken by objects that are not accelerated at all, because we are looking at them in an *accelerated*, *non-inertial* frame of reference, exactly as when we might look at the path of a dropped object in a rocket ship accelerating from thrust.

Comment: And saying that the effects are more or less *real* or *not real*, when the choice of which frame of reference you choose to look at them in totally changes how you *see* them is a bit foolish. It betrays a lack of understanding of what the issue is. Bottom line, If you can feel the force, it's real, if you can't then it is fictitious. Consider this, the only time we say we can "Feel" Gravity is when we are ***not*** accelerating. When we ***are*** accelerating due to gravity, (free fall), then we ***don't*** feel it. If this doesn't bother you a bit, then you don't understand this.

Comment: There are countless videos explaining this on the internet.  Here's a few... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XRr1kaXKBsU&pp=ygUfZ3Jhdml0eSBpcyBub3QgYSBmb3JjZSBlaW5zdGVpbg%3D%3D  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W3Jo6OCbuRk&pp=ygUfZ3Jhdml0eSBpcyBub3QgYSBmb3JjZSBlaW5zdGVpbg%3D%3D  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W3Jo6OCbuRk&pp=ygUfZ3Jhdml0eSBpcyBub3QgYSBmb3JjZSBlaW5zdGVpbg%3D%3D

Comment: The experience that created understanding for me was a diagram in a text by Wheeler, on page 33 of   https://ia800101.us.archive.org/24/items/GravitationMisnerThorneWheeler/Gravitation%20Misner%20Thorne%20Wheeler.pdf. (added to my answer above), In it he shows how the measured curvature of the geodesic (straight-line) path of a thrown baseball, a bullet fired from a gun, and a beam of light, all have exactly the same curvature. It's because the *perceived* is not a property of the moving object, it is a property of the acceleration of the frame of reference we are measuring things in.

Comment: Your quite natural, human bias towards considering that when standing or sitting on the surface of the earth, you are maintaining a *constant* velocity, and *not* accelerating, is due to the wrong assumption that there is a *preferred* absolute frame of reference, (that of the earth) and that acceleration is not relative, but absolute, and must always be measured relative to the Earth frame, and not to any other. In fact, GM says that the laws of Physics must be identical in all frames, and that Newtons Laws as he defined them are only valid in inertial or non-accelerated frames.

Comment: Charles, I know I won't win any argument with you on this point, but I'm with @Martin in terms of having an opinion that referring to anything we can directly experience as "fictitious" only serves to obfuscate common sense understanding for a majority of people.  (because why would you wear a G-suit to counter a "fictitious" force?)

Comment: Hah!  But we don't wear g-suits to counter the force of gravity! We wear them to counter the aerodynamic  force of ***Lift***! And the fact that you confuse the two makes my point.. Even if you want to consider gravity a *real* force, it is never greater than 1 G, and you don't need a g-suit for that. Do you wear one walking around in your kitchen?

Comment: And another quick point here. Your intuitive comment about   "*anything we can directly experience*" also betrays the essence of this misconception.  You do NOT experience the force of gravity. Even before physicists understood that gravity is not a force, but just the curvature of space-time, when they thought that it was a force, they understood that this gravitational force was not, and could not, be ***felt*** by anyone, as it affected every atom in your body *equally*. (except for the edge case represented by extremely strong tidal forces - also fictitious).

Comment: But is it more correct to say that we wear G-suits to counter lift, or the *effect* of lift?

Comment: Yes, in a way, you are correct. We wear g-suits to prorect against the physiological effects of *acceleration*, (as measured in any zero-g inertial frame), which is indeed the resuIts of all ***real*** forces, (mostly lift), acting on the aircraft

Comment: @CharlesBretana: this is starting to be more philosophical (my note was actually only  about choice of words anyway), but real=feel-able is not good universal measure neither, because feeling depends on particular organs/biology. We are actually not sensing absolute force, but difference over our body parts. You would definitively feel gravity in (strongly) non-homogeneous field despite being (your c.g.) in free fall. And same goes for other "fictitious" forces. (Beletry link: Neutron Star by Larry Niven :-) )

Comment: @Martin, it's not philosophical at all. This misconception is the source of most of the confusion about this topic. And understanding this eliminates all inconsistencies, and makes everything make sense.  And you don't *feel* gravity in non- homogeneous fields, you feel *tides*, which are the differentials or divergence of the geodesics.

Comment: But Neutron Star is an awesome novel!

Comment: Philosophical in sense what words "real", "to feel" etc. mean. There is definitively more ways to look at situations and whatever fits your "worldview" and gives correct prediction of objective outcomes is as good way as another. :)

Comment: @Martin, if you believe everyone has a right to their own reality, and their own definitions, then of course.... but then why engage in discourse?  True - that each of us may understand any word to represent a different concept to some degree, but this is not a black and white, on/off thing, it's along a spectrum, and we need to use words in a minimally consistent way to communicate rationally.

Comment: Again, I knew ahead of time I had no hope swaying you, I just think referring to an effect we can experience directly as fictitious is about as useful as man’splaining to your wife that her remark about feeling “normal stress” from preparing to host your family for Thanksgiving this year is incorrect, because normal stress is when a force acts perpendicular to the surface of an object.  If feels very pedantic to me…  Cheers.

Comment: But again, you keep referring to "*an effect we can experience directly*". I have made it pretty clear, crystal, in fact, that what you are experiencing is not gravity but the aerodynamic force of lift on the wing.

Answer (score 2):

Those diagrams, versions of which have been reproduced in many different flight training "ground school" materials, including some published by the FAA, are extremely misleading, and contain errors and omissions.

Slips and skids are *not* characterized by an "imbalance" between the pseudoforce called "centrifugal force", and the horizontal<sup>1</sup> component of the net aerodynamic force generated by the aircraft.

Rather, slips and skids can be said to be characterized by an imbalance between the pseudoforce called "centrifugal force", and the horizontal component of the *wing's lift force*.  (This isn't the simplest or most intuitive definition of a slip or skid, but it is a valid one.)

Since the pseudoforce called "centrifugal force" is actually just a mirror image of the horizontal component of the net aerodynamic force generated by the aircraft, the above statement is really just an overly complicated way of saying that in a slip or skid, *something other than the wing* is generating an aerodynamic force which has a horizontal component.

That "something" is the fuselage.  In a slip or skid, the airflow is striking the side of the fuselage, which generates a real aerodynamic sideforce, oriented perpendicular to the wing's lift vector.   Because the fundamental defining characteristic of a slip or skid is that *the nose of the aircraft is not aligned with the actual direction of travel through the airmass*, in the yaw axis.

If the aerodynamic sideforce generated by the airflow striking the side of the fuselage were included in the diagrams attached to the question, the horizontal component of the net aerodynamic force generated by the aircraft would be exactly equal in magnitude (and opposite in direction) to the "centrifugal force" vector *in every case.*

If the vectors labelled "HCL" are supposed to represent the *horizontal component of the net aerodynamic force generated by the aircraft*, including the horizontal component of the aerodynamic sideforce generated by the airflow striking the side of the fuselage, then they are drawn incorrectly.  For a given bank angle, the horizontal component of the net aerodynamic force generated by the aircraft is larger in a skidding turn than in a coordinated turn, and is smaller in a slipping turn than in a coordinated turn.  If the vector labelled "total lift" is supposed to represent the total aerodynamic force generated by the aircraft, including the sideforce contribution from the airflow striking the side of the fuselage, then the coordinated turn is the only case where the "total lift" vector should be exactly "square" to the wingspan.  In all cases the "centrifugal force" vector should be a mirror image of the vector representing the horizontal component of the net aerodynamic force generated by the aircraft.<sup>2</sup>

On the other hand, if the vectors labelled "HCL", "VCL", and "Total Lift" are only supposed to represent the horizontal, vertical, and total components of the *wing's lift vector*, then the diagrams become very confusing because the vector representing the aerodynamic sideforce generated by the airflow striking the side of the fuselage has been entirely omitted.  In this case the vectors labelled "centrifugal force" should still appear as described in the above paragraph, but in the slipping and skidding cases, the vector labelled "HCL" will no longer be a mirror image of the vector labelled "centrifugal force".  For a given bank angle, the wing's total lift vector, and therefore the horizontal and vertical components of the wing's lift vector, are all *slightly* smaller in a slipping turn than in a coordinated turn, because the aerodynamic sideforce generated by the airflow striking the side of the fuselage supports a small portion of the aircraft's weight.<sup>3</sup>  Similarly, in a skidding turn, the wing's total lift vector, and therefore the horizontal and vertical components of the wing's lift vector, are all *slightly* larger than in a coordinated turn, because the aerodynamic sideforce generated by the airflow striking the side of the fuselage contains an earthward component that must be opposed by the wing's lift vector.  These differences should be apparent in the vectors labelled "VCL" and "Total Lift" as well as the vectors labelled "HCL", and the vector labelled "Total Lift" should be "square" to the wingspan in all three cases.

Obviously the diagrams would be greatly improved by changing to an airmass-based reference frame rather than an aircraft-based reference frame, so that the "centrifugal force" vector could be entirely discarded, and by also including by the aerodynamic sideforce vector generated by the air striking the side of the fuselage.  There's no need to break things into horizontal and vertical components-- just show the wing's lift vector and the aerodynamic sideforce vector from the airflow striking the side of the fuselage.  These two vectors are oriented perpendicular to each other.  In a coordinated turn, there is no airflow striking the side of the fuselage, so the aerodynamic sideforce vector is zero, so the net aerodynamic force acts "straight up" in the aircraft's reference frame.  In a slip or a skid, the aerodynamic sideforce vector is not zero, and so the net aerodynamic force does not act "straight up" in the aircraft's reference frame.  End of story.  (If desired, an "apparent load" vector could be added, which would always be the mirror image of the vector sum of the wing's lift vector and the aerodynamic sideforce vector from the airflow striking the side of the fuselage.  Only in the case of the coordinated turn, where aerodynamic sideforce is zero, would the "apparent load" vector be exactly "square" to the wingspan.  And now-- keeping in mind that the weight vector makes no contribution to the "apparent load" vector-- we understand why the inclinometer ball behaves as it does in slipping, skidding, and coordinated turns.  And we've come to this understanding without ever invoking some sort of hypothetical "imbalance" between "centrifugal force" and some other force.  It all boils down to the question of whether the airflow is, or is not, striking the side of the fuselage and generating an aerodynamic sideforce vector.)

This concept was also explored in this related, highly upvoted question-- [What is missing from these diagrams of the forces in slips and skids?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/77528/what-is-missing-from-these-diagrams-of-the-forces-in-slips-and-skids)

***But as to your specific question:***

> If in a coordinated turn, the horizontal lift vector is equal to the
> Centrifugal force. Then how is the aircraft still turning?

Because when we include the pseudoforce called "centrifugal force" in our vector diagrams, we are using an aircraft-based reference frame rather than an airmass-based reference frame or ground-based reference frame.  Since the aircraft can't accelerate *relative to itself*, the net force in the aircraft-based reference frame will *always* be zero, whether the aircraft is turning or not.  In the aircraft-based reference frame, **the fact that the centrifugal force vector exists at all is actually evidence that the aircraft *is* turning.**  But for teaching purposes, using the aircraft-based reference frame (and therefore including the "centrifugal force" vector whenever the flight path is not linear) is arguably an inferior approach to using the airmass-based reference frame (and therefore not including any "centrifugal force" vector.)

Footnotes:

1. In this answer, when we talk about "horizontal", we mean as seen looking at the aircraft in a head-on view.  We're not referring to fore-and-aft forces such as thrust and drag.
2. Note that in the diagrams attached to the question, the illustrator chose to make the "total load" vectors in the "skidding turn" and "coordinated turn" identical, and to make the "HCL" (horizontal component of lift) vectors in the "slipping turn" and "coordinated turn" identical. That's all kind of random and makes no sense.
3. For an extreme case, consider sustained linear "knife-edge" flight at a 90-degree bank angle-- here the aerodynamic sideforce from the airflow striking the side of the fuselage is doing *all* the work of supporting the aircraft's weight, and the wing's lift vector is zero.

Comment: Re "In a coordinated turn, there is no airflow striking the side of the fuselage, so the aerodynamic sideforce vector is zero, so the net aerodynamic force acts "straight up" in the aircraft's reference frame."  -- maybe "in the aircraft's coordinate system." would be a better way to end this sentence.  The *reference frame* we are using here is that of the airmass, not the aircraft.  (Hence no need to include "centrifugal force".)

Comment: Regardless of whether we are taking the approach outlined in the 7th paragraph ("If the vectors labelled "HCL" are supposed to represent the *horizontal component of the net aerodynamic force generated by the aircraft*..."), or the 8th paragraph ("On the other hand, if the vectors labelled "HCL", "VCL", and "Total Lift" are only supposed to represent the horizontal, vertical, and total components of the *wing's lift vector*..."), it makes no sense whatsoever for the HCL vector in the "skidding" case to be *smaller* than the HCL vector in the "coordinated" case.  It should be *larger*.

Comment: Likewise, at least if following approach outlined in 7th para, in the skidding case the Total Lift vector should be tilted further to the *inside* of the turn than in the coordinated case, not closer to vertical.  And the Total Load vector should reflect this, being a mirror-image of the Total Lift vector.  This set of diagrams really is completely flawed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm gonna go out on a limb and suggest that all of these answers seem to be answering a different question than "why does the airplane turn" when the bank is such that the acceleration in the airplane's rest frame points straight down (a coordinated turn). A ball on a string swung over your head moves in a circle without any aerodynamic forces. So there's something else going on.

Part of the problem is conflating turn = "move in a circle" with turn = yaw.

You can have a banked airplane where the wing lift vector points off to one side but the airplane doesn't turn. Every PPL candidate has to demonstrate a slip to landing, which is exactly that - the rudder input exactly opposes the yaw tendency created by the horizontal relative wind component.

What that highlights is that the yaw is *caused* by the side-force of the relative wind on the tail. The horizontal relative wind at the tail is caused by the horizontal lift component created by the bank. In a constant rate turn the rate of yaw must match the rate of turn, but that doesn't mean the airplane's nose has to be pointed along the tangent of the turning circle.

If the apparent "g" in the airplane frame is not straight down, that will cause a horizontal wind component on the tail which will yaw the plane. If the horizontal "g" points to the inside of the turn, the effective wind will yaw the nose to the inside of the turn & vice versa. That's why you can make a turn without using any rudder - the "g" to the inside will create enough yaw to keep the plane turning. But it's less aerodynamic than if you get all the yaw from having inside rudder input instead of depending on inside "g". So "coordinated turn" = "apparent g straight down".

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149347/discussion-on-answer-by-foster-boondoggle-if-in-a-coordinated-turn-the-horizont); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score -3):

Newton’s first law.  If the forces are perfectly in balance then the aircraft will continue to turn at a constant rate.

Comment: No, that's not true. With forces in balance (as seen from the given reference frame), the movement will continue along _straight_ line with constant speed.

Comment: An object moving at a constant velocity is not accelerating, **all** forces considered.  Notice, in a turn, fuel input (power) must be increased, due to increased drag.  But once in the turn, fuel burn is *constant*.

Comment: @Martin ok the principle is more succinctly described by conservation of angular momentum but if you consider the aircraft as a collection of individual components then 3rd law applies; the frame of reference is the aircraft as a whole, it ‘sees’ the universe rotating around it and there’s no resultant force that would change it.

Comment: ***Anytime*** you attempt to analyze a scenario within, or with reference to, a non- inertial or  *accelerated* Frame of reference, (one in which a g-meter will show *any* non-zero value), you ***must*** include some non-inertial or fictitious forces that represent the acceleration of the frame of reference itself or Newton's laws will not work - they will no longer be valid.